# ONE RegionServer not receive any Regions on hbase

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

- I have a pain when running Hbase.
- when reboot a regionServer.., I don’t know why total regions not distribution balance between RegionServer after reboot success..

  RegionServer not serve any Regions as picture

  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this thing can happen when you have regions stuck in transition - in this case balancer does not work and num regions for some RS is 0 - that means all regions are already assigned to other RegionServers.

If this is your case - one way (preferrable) is to fix regions in transition, other way is to restart all RS so they reassign regions on start and you'll have better distribution.

Comment: dear MrAdam, could tell me how to fix regions in transaction ?? ( I know that hbase auto hash record to region belong the key of record).

Comment: @chanvit it depends, the easiest way is to run hbase hbck -repair in shell. it works sometimes, but sometimes it does not help. sometimes restarting the whole cluster can help. also I've seen situation when nothing can help and you have to delete and recreate table from backup